# How do i output the attributes of objects stored in a java vector?

Tags: java, vector

I have created several objects of a custom class and assigned them different attributes. I have then added each of those objects to a vector but when i try to output the elements of the vector, all i get are references to the objects and not the object attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access them with the [enhanced `for` loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with):

```
Vector<YourObject> vector = ...;

for(YourObject obj : vector)
{
    System.out.println(obj.YOUR_METHOD_OR_ATTRIBUTE);
}
```

Or by using [`elementAt(position)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#elementAt%28int%29):

```
System.out.println(vector.elementAt(position).YOUR_METHOD_OR_ATTRIBUTE);
```

Or finally, override the `toString()` method and use:

```
System.out.println(vector.elementAt(position));
```

Comment: The enhanced for loop worked out great for me as i wanted to output multiple attributes without repetition. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `System.out.println()` (or a similar method) and pass it a reference to an instance of a class an implicit call to that class's `toString()` method is made. What you're seeing is the default implementation of `toString()` inherited from the `Object` class.

If you want to change the output simply provide your own implementation of `toString()` in your class that returns the information you want.

Answer (score 1):

When you print an instance of any class, toString() method of `Object` class is called..

You need to override `toString` method in your Custom class, and print the attribute you want.. Then your `toString()` method will be called instead of `Object's` toString..

Or, you can have a `getter` method, and invoke that on each instance of

```
public class Custom {
    private String attr;

    public String getAttr() {
         return this.attr;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
         return attr;
    }
}
```

Then when you print your instance, `toString()` will be invoked, and `attr` value will get printed.

```
Vector<Custom> yourVector = ...;

for (Custom val: yourVector) {
    System.out.println(val);  // Will invoke `toString()` and print attr value.
    System.out.println(val.getAttr());  // Prints attr value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's important to use generics on your Vector. If you don't, you will get objects of type java.lang.Object unless you cast them.

So define it like this:

```
Vector<MyObject> vector = new Vector<MyObject>();
```

instead of

```
Vector vector = new Vector();
```

Comment: @mindhaq.. And how did you assume that OP is not doing either of them??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `System.out.println(v)`, where v is your `Vector` of elements, then you need to implement the `toString()` method of your custom objects. This way you will override the default Object#toString() behavior that you now get.